# Will my application run as administrator?

Tags: c#, process, administrator, process.start, runas

If my application requires itself to be run as an administrator, and then executes

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

Will the child process be run as administrator as well, or do I need to run it as administrator specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in most cases.

From MSDN:

> Each application that requires the administrator access token must
>   prompt the administrator for consent. The one exception is the
>   relationship that exists between parent and child processes. Child
>   processes inherit the user access token from the parent process.

Your child process will have the same rights as the parent. There are some exceptions. I'd suggest reading this page:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835561(v=ws.10).aspx